# warning: control reaches end of non-void function - Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, virtual

I'm having an issue with polymorphism at the moment it seems. I have a base class called Asset, then 3 classes that inherit from that class - Bond, Saving and Stock. There is a function inside the Asset class called value() which is not implemented in this class, but rather in each of the derived classes. I came across some errors and was told that I should make the function `virtual` which stopped the compiler telling me I never implemented the function. But now I'm getting the error `Warning: control reaches end of non-void function` and my code won't run. I just added a `cout << "Testing";` at the beginning of my code and still nothing. Here is my Asset class and then one of the implemented functions.

`Asset.h`

```
#ifndef ASSET_H
#define ASSET_H

#include <QString>
#include <QDate>

class Asset
{
public:
    Asset(QString, QDate);
    virtual double value() {};
    QString getDescription();
    QString getType();
protected:
    QString type;
    QDate date;
private:
    QString description;
};

#endif
```

`Stock.cpp value function`

```
double Stock::value()
{
    return sharePrice*numShares;    
}
```

I understand it's tough trying to piece together my code snippets. It doesn't seem decent to post all the files, there are a few. But I've linked the whole project onto Google Drive if you'd like to view it. `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4hZjZFvvaTiWWlhXzF0YWQtcmc/edit?usp=sharing`

Comment: If you don't implement a function in the base class, you have to make it *pure* virtual. But since you don't show all relevant code, people can only guess what you are doing. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You have multiple definitions of the `value` function. Seems like the correct way for your code would be replacing the one in the class with `double value();`, unless you mean for it to be overridden, in which case `virtual double value();`. And if this is a base class, it should probably have a virtual destructor.

Comment: 1. Don't use float for currencies. 2. Read the warning and re-read it until you understand it. It says it is reaching end of a non-void function and it doesn't have a value to return. You can't just leave it hanging. That's exactly what your Asset::value() function is doing.

Comment: Also, in Qt 5, you should be marking all derived functions with [`Q_DECL_OVERRIDE`](http://woboq.com/blog/cpp11-in-qt5.html) to indicate your intent. The C++11 compiler will then issue an error and fail to compile code where you mismatch the signature of the overriding method with the signature of intended method to override.

Comment: **Don't use float for currencies** Seriously. Just don't. Even if it "appears" to work.

Comment: All of these fields were given to me in UML diagrams. Even if I wanted to change things like using double I cant

Answer (score 3):

You have an unintended implementation (definition) for your function. In your class declaration change

```
class Asset {
    // ...
    virtual double value() {};
                        // ^^   <<<<<<<<<<< You don't want this
    // ...
};
```

to

```
class Asset {
    // ...
    virtual double value() = 0;
    // ...
};
```

In class `Stock` override the function

```
class Stock : public Asset {
    // ...
    virtual double value();
    // ...
};
```

The rest of the implementation is fine as it was before.

Answer (score 1):

In looking at the code you have posted, I see an issue with `Asset::value()`, in that it doesn't return anything, and is likely the cause for the error that you show. Your two options are to make it pure virtual

```
virtual double value() = 0;
```

or to return a default value (likely 0)

```
virtual double value() {return 0.0;}
```

If this does not fix your issue, you should post more code.

Comment: There's still another definition in the implementation file.

Comment: The OP surely doesn't want do declare a pure function here!

Comment: @chris, I orginally thought that, but the implementation is for `Stock` and not `Asset`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I could see a pure function being the right answer here, given that `Asset` is a base class for his three other classes.

Comment: The function is implemented differently in 3 classes. I tried this and I just got a massive output from the compiler and still nothing worked :(

Comment: @nickcorin If the compiler no longer complained about the control reaching the end of a non-void function, then it seems that this has solved the issue that you posted.

Comment: @JoelRondeau You are right, in `Asset` the OP probably wants a pure function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, fixed, with commentary.

```
class Currency {
  // Never use a floating point type for currency.
  // Wrap, for example, Intel's DFP
  // http://www.netlib.org/misc/intel/
  ...
};

class Asset
{
    // Since you didn't implement the copy constructor,
    // and assignment operator, you must
    // disable the copying. Otherwise, you must implement them all,
    // and ideally the move constructor as well.
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Asset)
public:
    // In Qt, it's idiomatic to pass the complex types via const
    // reference, although it's not end of the world not to do so.
    // Both are OK, since those "complex" types are cheap to copy.
    Asset(const QString &, const QDate &);
                    /** or **/
    Asset(QString, QDate);
    // A virtual destructor is necessary for a class that
    // can be derived from. Otherwise, inevitable type slicing will
    // lead to bugs. Remember: anyone is free to destruct the
    // derived class through a pointer to the base class!
    virtual ~Asset();
    // This is an abstract method, declare it as such.
    // It should also be const, since it's a getter.
    virtual Currency value() const = 0;
    // Getters should be const. The get prefix is redundant.
    QString description() const; 
    QString type() const;
protected:
    // Member data should have an agreed-upon prefix,
    // to prevent bugs when a local variable is referenced
    // instead of a member, and vice-versa.
    QString m_type;
    QDate m_date;
private:
    QString m_description;
};

class Stock : public Asset
{
   ...
public:
   // Q_DECL_OVERRIDE will trigger a compiler error
   // if we're not overriding a virtual method.
   Currency value() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
   ...
};
```